# Binding a Java application to an interface

Tags: java, linux, ip

I have root access to a GNU/Linux server with 2 interfaces. I'm using Jericho and HtmlUnit to crawl some web pages. I want to specify which interface should be used for the HTTP connection. Is there a way to do this in either the command line or Java?

Answer (score 2):

> *I want to specify which interface should be used for the HTTP connection.*

Each network interface has its own unique IP address(es).  You bind to an interface by connecting to a port on the interfaces's IP Address.

> *I don't have access to sockets. I'm giving HtmlUnit a URL.*

Whether you are using sockets (via `Socket` / `InetAddress`) or HTTP connections (via `URL`), you use the same approach - bind to an IP Address + Port.

**Determine Which Interface Has Which Address(es)**

- Use a Linux Command:

  ```
   ip a
   ip link show
   /sbin/ifconfig -a
   lshw -class network
  ```
- Use Java (`java.net.NetworkInterface` class):

  ```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.net.*;
   import java.util.*;
   import static java.lang.System.out;

   public class ListNIFs {
       public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {
           Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = 
               NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

           for (NetworkInterface netIf : Collections.list(nets)) {
               out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netIf.getDisplayName());
               out.printf("Name: %s\n", netIf.getName());
               Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netIf.getInetAddresses();
               for (InetAddress add : Collections.list(inetAddresses)) {
                   out.printf("Address: %s\n", add.getName().getAddress().getHostAddress());
               }
               displaySubInterfaces(netIf);
               out.printf("\n");
           }
       }

       static void displaySubInterfaces(NetworkInterface netIf) throws SocketException {
           Enumeration<NetworkInterface> subIfs = netIf.getSubInterfaces();            
           for (NetworkInterface subIf : Collections.list(subIfs)) {
               out.printf("\tSub Interface Display name: %s\n", subIf.getDisplayName());
               out.printf("\tSub Interface Name: %s\n", subIf.getName());
               Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = subIf.getInetAddresses();
               for (InetAddress add : Collections.list(inetAddresses)) {
                   out.printf("\t Sub Interface Address: %s\n", add.getName().getAddress().getHostAddress());
               }
           }
        }
   }
  ```

**HTML Unit: Specify IP Address and Port**

If you're invoking `HTMLUnit`'s `WebClient`,  E.g.:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage page = 
    webClient.getPage("http://mycompany.org/mypage");
```

then you can do any of the following:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage page = 
    webClient.getPage("http://255.255.255.0:80/mypage");

java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://255.255.255.0:80/mypage");
page = webClient.getPage(url);

com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest req = 
    new com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest(url, com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpMethod.GET);
page = webClient.getPage(req);
```

You can also use a `HTMLUnit` `HttpWebConnection`:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection conn = 
    new com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection(webClient);
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://255.255.255.0/mypage");
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest req = 
    new com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest(url, com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpMethod.POST);
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest resp = conn.getResponse(req);
```

**Core Java: Options To Specify URL for HTTP Connection**

Create a URL to connect to a resource (file, web page, etc).  You can specify URL with host string (automatic DNS lookup) OR IP address.  You can optionally add the port:

```
    // does not encode URL for you (manually include %20, etc)
    java.net.URL url = 
        new URL("http://255.255.255.20:80/docs/books/tutorial/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");
    java.net.URL url2 = new URL("http", "255.255.255.20", 80, 
                                "/docs/books/tutorial/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");
    java.net.URL url3 = new java.net.URL("https://maps.google.com/maps?q=sydney");
    java.net.URL url4 = new java.net.URL("https", "maps.google.com", 80, "/maps?q=sydney");

    // does encoding of URL string for you 
    java.net.URI uri5 = new URI("http", "example.com", "/hello world/", "");
    java.net.URL url5 = uri2.toURL();

    // Can then pass URL to HTMLUnit, or invoke yourself 
    // (see Java Network Tutorial for details):

    java.net.URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    java.net.HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection)conn;
    // preconnection: call setAllowUserInteraction/setDoInput/setDoOutput/    
    //                     setIfModifiedSince/setUseCaches/setRequestProperty
    httpConn.connect();  // or getInputStream/getOutputStream/getContent/getHeaderField
    // postconnection: call getContentEncoding/getContentLength/getContentType
    //                      getDate/getExpiration/getLastModifed
```

**Core Java: Options To Specify InetAddress (for Socket Connection)**

Using IP Address

```
    // 4 bytes:
    byte[] ip4Address = {101,119,11,106};  
    java.net.InetAddress addressObj = java.net.InetAddress.getByAddress(ip4Address); 

    // or use ip6Address, 16 bytes (2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334):
    // Any hex value above 0x7f must be cast to byte, because byte is signed (-128 to 127)
    byte[] ip6Address = {0x20,0x01,0x0d,(byte)0xb8,(byte)0x85,(byte)0xa3,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,(byte)0x8a,0x2e,0x03,0x70,0x73,0x34};
```

Using URL String (DNS Lookup)

```
    java.net.InetAddress addressObj = java.net.InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
```

Comment: Is 255.255.255.0 the local IP of one of my interfaces or the remote IP of mycompany.org ?

Comment: It's the IP address of the interface you would like to invoke using the socket. i.e. wherever the page is - presumably mycompany.org

Comment: This is not clear to me. I want to reach an external web page, from one of my interfaces. So any method that I need to call should involve both the external web site AND the IP of my interface.

Comment: @mossaab Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

In Java you have to bind the Socket to the local IP adress of the NIC you want to use.
If you're using 0.0.0.0 it binds to ALL.
Specified it uses just the one you want.

Comment: I don't have access to sockets. I'm giving HtmlUnit a URL.

Comment: What did the HtmlUnit Docu say about this, then?

Comment: Nothing. It's just calling Apache Commons HttpClient. Jericho doesn't use this library. I'm not trying to look into the specific details of these libraries. What I'm trying to do is something like: "Hey, Java, why don't you use the IP address A.B.C.D for every IP calls?"

Comment: Why don't you have a look at the implementation if it's open source (it's the greatest advantage of this concept)? Find the Class of the Library which binds the sockets, change or extend it and say: "Hey Lib-Socket-Implementation, use this IP"! Sorry, but it's the most constructive advise I have at this point, because I'm not familiar with any of your libs...

Comment: Please ignore that there are libraries involved here and note that my question is about Java and/or Linux, not about a specific library. I'm not manually creating a socket. I want to instantiate HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection(), and to make sure that it goes through a specific interface.

Comment: I've understand you, don't panic. But when the lib does not offering a parameter or system property or somewhat other config, you're asking how to check the motor oil without opening the car hood. So you have to bet and hope that the lib is using the socket implementation from rt.jar and override just this class while tying it on the nic you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to make it.

1. In Java, the key point is specifying the source address you want to use before invoking HTTPConnection#open() method:

   InetAddress favourateAddr = InetAddress(byte[] {1,2,3,4}); // 1.2.3.4 is the ip address of the NIC you want to use

   yourHTTPConnObj.setLocalAddress(favourateAddr);

   // then open http connection
   yourHTTPConnObj.open();
2. In Linux, it is the layer 3 utils that determines the routing who will select the NIC. so you need to use the target address to customize the route table to force your connection starts from which NIC. It's very simple, just a single route command. see [this link](http://www.jroller.com/agileanswers/entry/specify_source_ip_address_in).

Comment: I've tried `sudo /sbin/route add -host 8.8.8.8 dev eth1`. But when I ping on 8.8.8.8, I get `Destination Host Unreachable`.